# Missing WEB-INF file in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat, web-inf

I'm collaborating via Git to create a Dynamic Web Project that uses JSPs.

Since some arbitrary point a couple of days ago, I found that the project would refuse to run on the server, because Tomcat wasn't recognising the imports at the top of the JSP files - which was bizarre, because the compiler wasn't complaining at all.

After a while I realised this is probably because at some point (I suppose due to a commit by someone else) the WEB-INF directory has disappeared. I've tried deleting the project from the workspace and re-importing it to get it back, but it doesn't work.

Is WEB-INF probably the problem, and if so how can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the platform that you're working on and obviously are not very experienced in git. You should use some graphical UI for git (actually eclipse is a start, choose *Team/Show in history* on the project) and then check the last days commits: You'll see who added which lines or committed with which comment.

Alternatively, find graphical git UI for the platform you're running.

And yes, a webapplication requires WEB-INF/web.xml as the deployment descriptor. If it's deleted, it most likely won't run. And typically there's quite a bit more in WEB-INF that's also required, e.g. WEB-INF/lib contains the code of the webapplication - at least after deployment. These don't need to be there during development, but at least the build process should take care of these files/directories. At least some content typically is there during development time already